# Did the Bar Kokhba revolt happen before or after Jerusalem's name was changed to Aelia?

Tags: roman-empire, christianity, jerusalem, judaism

There are conflicting views with respect to this on the net. 
[Wikipedia's summary of the names of Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Jerusalem#Greco-Roman) asserts that the name was changed before the [Bar Kokhba revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Kokhba_revolt), and that was one of the cause of the revolt.

> Aelia Capitolina was the Roman name given to Jerusalem in the 2nd century, after the destruction of the Second Temple.

(the Bar-Kokhba revolt is recorded at 132-136 CE)

[Wikipedia's summary of the Bar Kokhba revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Kokhba_revolt#Immediate_consequences) places, states that the name changed happened **after** the revolt, as a way of ensuring such things never happened again.

> Hadrian . . .  re-established Jerusalem, but now as the Roman pagan polis of Aelia Capitolina . . .

Which is correct?

Also, was the statue of Jupiter in Jersusalem (in the holy sanctuary?), constructed before or after the revolt ?

Comment: Added the source for "other places"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main sources, [Cassius Dio](http://www.livius.org/ja-jn/jewish_wars/bk05.html), says that Hadrian renamed Jerusalem,
and as a result of this the uprising started:

This source is considered trustworthy in general.